# #1061 - when creating a ENUM field

Tags: phpmyadmin, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a `ENUM` field inside my database, but everytime i'm trying to save this the following error occurs:

`#1064 - There is something wrong in your syntax at '0) CHARACTERS SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL DEFAULT NULL' at line 1`

Don't know the exact translation because it's set in dutch but should be something like above.

---

**What i'm trying to do**

Create a new `ENUM` field with the values `'invoice', 'delivery', 'contact'` and the default value set to `NULL`.

**Screenshot (for Dutch/English people)**

[Screenshot when trying to save this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBbd6.png)

Can someone tell me if i'm doing something wrong, thought about reserved keyword but I don't think there are any inside this value.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version do you have? (The version information can be see on the main page after logging in, for instance).

Comment: Hello, currently the version 4.6.4

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is marked as a bug on PHPMyAdmin, this should be fixed within version 4.6.5 according to the [Github issues](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12529) page.